# Production equivalent to Spring Boot EmbeddedServletContainerCustomizer

Tags: spring-boot

My question relates to Spring Boot and how to configure error pages in a production web app running in cloudfoundry.

In the Spring IO Sagan reference application, I noticed in the  [MvcConfig](https://github.com/spring-io/sagan/blob/master/sagan-site/src/main/java/sagan/MvcConfig.java#L110), the following code:

```
@Configuration
    public static class ErrorConfig implements EmbeddedServletContainerCustomizer {

        @Override
        public void customize(ConfigurableEmbeddedServletContainer factory) {
            factory.addErrorPages(new ErrorPage(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND, "/404"));
            factory.addErrorPages(new ErrorPage(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR, "/500"));
        }

    }
```

Is this configuration used in the cloud too? If so why is it named: **`EmbeddedServletContainerCustomizer`**? If not what is the equivalent for the cloud?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can use `EmbeddedServletContainerCustomizer` when deploying to the cloud. Sagan itself is doing exactly that on CloudFoundry for the [spring.io](http://spring.io) website.

The "embedded" in the name of `EmbeddedServletContainerCustomizer` refers to the fact that the servlet container is embedded in your application's [executable jar file](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#getting-started-first-application-executable-jar).  It's the recommended approach for [cloud deployment](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#cloud-deployment).